# How to execute a curl command into javascript using a function or using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, curl

I'm working with forge autodesk API ,and i still have a problem with access token is expired in 1 h ,so I want to create a script using this CURL

(
`curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate' -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'client_id=pOu8oDwa5G6TcGaqzogHFQCZPojl879h&client_secret=BcCph2Y4Q7Drm6Ju&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=data:read'`
)

to executed it into a javascript and get a new access token

this is my CURL:

`curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate' -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'client_id=pOu8oDwa5G6TcGaqzogHFQCZPojl879h&client_secret=BcCph2Y4Q7Drm6Ju&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=data:read'`

Comment: Need to send request to your server and run that curl from there. Highly unlikely that api is cors enabled to prevent you from exposing credentials client side

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The modern way to send an HTTP request through javascript is [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

However, given that the HTTP POST involves a client secret key, I would recommend generating these tokens server-side such that somebody can't run away with your secret key and use the autodesk API under your name